# What is this black and white graphical style called?

Tags: style, style-identification

[image: Mighty Boosh with Colors Removed]

What is this style refereed to as? Image is from a promotion for the show The Mighty Boosh. I keep wanting to call it Banksy but that's not it...

Comment: "Late-Era Xerox."

Comment: That's gotta be close at least...

Comment: Could it be called 1-bit color pallet maybe?

Comment: Lauren, I love your sense of humor. "Neo-Xerox" might also work.

Comment: Well, it's clearly not an *early* Xerox, or you'd have a lot more detail. This is like 20th-generation Xerox.

Comment: Threshold Style? xD

Comment: @leeand00 Don't know that Banksy would appreciate :). When you say "style", I think of words like "Bauhaus", "Art Nouveau", and "Modern". How about "Photo-Minimalism"?

Comment: @Dawson My intention wasn't to insult the work of Banksy.  He has really good art.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knockout image, reverse, or Photocopy.

Answer (score 2):

Forgetting entirely about the lettering for a moment, and just sticking to the photography, this picture represents what you would get with **litho** film. An extreme contrast film, litho (usually *ortho litho* these days, or *orthochromatic lithography* film, which can be used under relatively bright red safe lights) is characterized by large blocks of tone that are either "on" or "off", with essentially no intermediate tones at all; individual grains have a hair-trigger exposure threshold, and development is "contagious", so black areas will bleed together. That film type has been used for halftone offset lithography and serigraphy (silkscreen printing) pre-press repro work for, oh, a hundred years or so, so it predates xerography by just a little bit. This picture represents what you would get using ortho film without a halftone screen (and likely with a bit of additional hand-masking with paint/ink and ferricyanide bleach or something like rubylith appliqués). That technique was used commercially *and* found its way into a number of schools of art over the years

That said, the effect *in this application* seems obviously designed to look like late-'70s/early-'80s-era photocopied flyers/'zines. Basically, you had a choice: pay for the Letraset halftone overlay sheet (which was like $20 for a two-pack of letter-size in those days, when $20 was an awful lot of pocket change) so you could get a reasonable-looking continuous-tone image, or just run a photo through a photocopier, adjust the contrast, modify with marker and correction fluid, rinse and repeat until you got a useful "master" (under a dollar, especially if you could do it at school without getting caught). (The real work was in hand-colouring the blue lettering with Hi-Liters.) So Lauren's offhand comment is really the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't really have one yet I think, " Street Art Stenciling " seems to be the closest - If you can get the UK channel 4od check - http://www.channel4.com/programmes/graffiti-wars/4od - and the documentary "Exit through the Gift Shop" which were on a couple of days ago, both covering the artists who do a similar style to the one above.

Comment: Boooo. The post is a photograph with Levels, Threshold, or Curves gone awry via Photoshop. Banksy's work has much more detail, style, and is not done for commercial purposes.

Comment: @Dawson Fair enough, I didn't intend to insult his work.  I find it inspiring.

Comment: @leeand00 - It's cool. I was boo-ing this comment. The word "Stenciling" didn't sit well with me. I know that may be part of the process, but I know there's a lot more to it than that, where Banksy's concerned. I also see his work as trying to say something rather than sell something - that's what forced the "boo" out of me.

Answer (score 1):

It can be referred as duotone art.

See for exampe [Wikipedia-Duotone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duotone)  and  [printer national-duotone](http://www.printernational.org/what-is-duotone.php)

Comment: That isn't really duotone... And the links you reference look nothing like the image posted.

Answer (score 0):

heavy blocks of text are pretty indicative of modernism from the swiss movement and the stripped down graphic is dadaism, and since both of those styles are heavily appropriated here, i'd call it post-modern. well more pastiche than anything else. but yea. post-modernism.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call it two value notan photography

Comment: Why? Or should that be better an comment, I guess?